# My current issue is that I have this: and I cannot figure out how to make this NOT push things to the right when there are differing lengths of text

Tags: javascript

```
rowText = " " + this.rpad(itm, 2) + 
          " | " + this.lpad(quantity, 1) + 
          " | " + this.rpad(uom, 2) +  
          " | " + this.rpad(pn, 13) + 
          " | " + this.rpad(desc, 26) + 
          " | " + this.rpad(rd, 12) + 
          " | " + this.rpad(vnd, 25) + 
          " | " + this.rpad(cg, 6) + " | " + this.rpad(nts, 8);
```

As the text lengths differ in rows, this pushes to the right. I would like something as tab delim to create quasi columns.

when I try adding `/T` I get an error

Comment: If you dont want things padded to the right, then don't use `this.rpad`, so instead of `this.rpad(itm,2)` just replace it with `itm`

Comment: _"when I try adding `/T` I get an error"_ The tab character is normally ```\t```

Comment: Why not use an HTML table?  this is exactly what they're designed for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Why not add all items in an array and join it with custom separator.

<!-- language: lang-js -->
    this.populateBOMList = function(document) {
        var i, compId, comp, rowText;
        var dirty = document.dirty;
        if (!document.notify3DAnnotPageOpen) {
            document.notify3DAnnotPageOpen = function() {
                document.akBom.createSelectionLookups(document);
                setInitialView(document);
            };
        }

        this.buildTopLevelComponents(document);
        var listBoxItems = [];
        for (i = 0; i < this.bomListOccurrenceIds.length; i++) {
            var occId = this.bomListOccurrenceIds[i][0];
            compId = document.anarkCoreData.getEntityById(occId).componentId;
            comp = document.anarkCoreData.getEntityById(compId);
            var quantity = this.getBomQuantityAsString(document, i);
            var itm = comp.Attributes["ITEM"] || comp.name;
            var uom = comp.Attributes["UOM"] || comp.name;
            var pn = comp.Attributes["Part Number"] || comp.name;
            var rd = comp.Attributes["REF DES"] || comp.name;
            var vnd = comp.Attributes["Vendor"] || comp.name;
            var cg = comp.Attributes["CAGE"] || comp.name;
            var nts = comp.Attributes["NOTES"] || comp.name;
            var desc = comp.Attributes["Description"] || comp.Attributes["InventorSummaryInformationCoded/Title"] || "N/A";


    rowText = [itm \t quantity \t uom \t pn \t desc \t rd \t vnd \t cg \t nts] ;
    
    
        
            rowText = this.avoidCollisions(rowText, listBoxItems);
            var itemPair = [];
            itemPair.push(rowText);
            itemPair.push(i.toString());
            listBoxItems.push(itemPair);
        }
        if (listBoxItems.length) {
            this.bomListBox.setItems(listBoxItems);
            this.clearBomListBoxSelection();
        }
        document.dirty = dirty;
    };

    this.doesTextCollide = function(rowText, listBoxItems) {
        for (var i = 0; i < listBoxItems.length; i++) {
            var text = listBoxItems[i][0];
            if (text === rowText) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    this.avoidCollisions = function(rowText, listBoxItems) {
        var newText = rowText.toString();
        var count = 1;
        while (this.doesTextCollide(newText, listBoxItems)) {
            count++;
            newText = rowText.toString() + "              (" + count.toString() + ")";
        }
        return newText;
    };
    
    this.rpad = function (textString, length) {
        if (!textString)
            textString = "";
        var str = textString.toString().substring(0, length);
        while (str.length < length)
            str = str + ' ';
        return str;
    };

    this.lpad = function (textString, length) {
        if (!textString)
            textString = "";
        var str = textString.toString().substring(0, length);
        while (str.length < length)
            str = ' ' + str;
        return str;
    };
```

Comment: I like the much shorter line, but it still pushes text, I am trying to simulate a table's columns.

Comment: then you need to get another array with length and map the padded items.

Comment: ok, sorry to be stooopid, I am a Mech. Engineer/CAD admin. I have been tasked with evolving the Anark code that produces 3D pdf's from Solidworks/Inventor assemblies. My ignorance exposed, is there a way to make each item in rowText have a certain # of characters, regardless of what the text is? Like pn is Part Number & can have between 7 and 13 characters. I would like to say that should be 14 characters long, not 14 + the part number. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: you could add a slicing in advance for the length and than apply padding with same value.

Comment: Or a way to TAB between?

Comment: does `'\t'` not work?

Comment: It gives me a syntax error, but i could be invoking it wrongly, or maybe the other code? this is the entire bit of code for the part list:

Comment: how do i post the code here, about 3k chars?

Comment: rowText = [itm\t quantity\t uom\t pn\t desc\t rd\t vnd\t cg\t nts]. ;
 
  }

Comment: `rowText` is not working like that. if you want to add tabs between strings, you could join with that string, like `rowText = [itm, quantity].join('\t');`

Comment: not sure of the syntax here.

Comment: That kind of works, if the length doesn't end where it would need 2 tabs

Comment: just add as many tabs a you want at the end of the string, or add one for two inside of the array for joining.